# Regex: Select and Delete everything that is framed in the comments html tags

Tags: powershell, notepad++, regex, powershell-ise, microsoft-expression

I have this html code. And I want to select/delete everything that falls between the comments `<!-- ARTICOL START -->` and `<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->` except all those `<p class=..</p>` lines. Can this be done with regex?

```
  <!-- ARTICOL START -->

<div align="justify">
        <table width="682" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td><h1 class="den_articol" itemprop="sfe">My text here</h1></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text_dreapta">On Ianuarie 14, 2014, in <a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/qualities-of-a-leader.html" title="See al articles from  Qualities of a leader" class="external" rel="category tag">Qualities of a leader</a>, by Author</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      <h2 class="text_obisnuit2"><img src="index_files/sfa.jpg" width="718" height="605" id="sfs" usemap="#m_dgrnt" alt="hip" /><map name="tfAbonament" id="m_34">
<area shape="rect" coords="259,545,457,582" href="#plata" alt="" />
</map></h2>
        <p class="den_articol">Why this text text?</p>
<p class="text_obisnuit">test text text</p>
        <p class="text_obisnuit">test text text</p>
  <p class="text_obisnuit2">test text text</p>
    </div>
    <p align="justify" class="text_obisnuit style3">&nbsp;</p>
   
       <!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->
```

**The output should be:**

```
       <!-- ARTICOL START -->

        <p class="den_articol">Why this text text?</p>
<p class="text_obisnuit">test text text</p>
        <p class="text_obisnuit">test text text</p>
  <p class="text_obisnuit2">test text text</p>
   
       <!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->
```

**I made a regex, but is not working:**

Find: `(<\!-- ARTICOL START -->).*(?!<p class=.*</p>).*(<\!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)`

Replace by: `\1\2\3`

Also, I believe this task can be done with **PowerShell**, without using regex. If someone knows better PowerShell. But powershell must modify all html files from the `c:\Folder1`.

Comment: Independent of whether or not it can technically be done, regex isn't good for parsing HTML and extracting particular tags. You're likely better off using tools designed to do that type of thing (e.g. such as [Python](https://www.python.org/) with the [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) module, including its [associated documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)).

Comment: I am very sure that @Toto will find a regex solution :)

Comment: Try something like this in PowerShell, I know it isn't very good, but it does get the job done: `get-content D:\test.html | where {$_ -match "ARTICOL|<P class=(.*)</p>"}`.

Comment: thank you @XeнεiΞэnвϵς but can you write the entire your PowerShell code in a answer, as to test it and vote it if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Notepad++:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\h*<!-- ARTICOL START -->\R|\G)\K(?:(<p class=.*?</p>\R?)|(?:(?!<p class=.*?</p>)[\s\S])+)(?=[\s\S]+<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/G5mLGp/1)

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: super answer @Toto , thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this is the regex way to parse html files, in fact this is a very very bad idea and I can use (much) more complex PowerShell and Python 3 codes to do it more properly right now but you asked for the regex way, so I will just give what you asked for, since your html code is not all that complex.

So I copy pasted your code into Notepad++ and saved it as a text file with the extension of .html, I saved it at D:\test.html

```
  <!-- ARTICOL START -->

<div align="justify">
        <table width="682" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td><h1 class="den_articol" itemprop="sfe">My text here</h1></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text_dreapta">On Ianuarie 14, 2014, in <a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/qualities-of-a-leader.html" title="See al articles from  Qualities of a leader" class="external" rel="category tag">Qualities of a leader</a>, by Author</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      <h2 class="text_obisnuit2"><img src="index_files/sfa.jpg" width="718" height="605" id="sfs" usemap="#m_dgrnt" alt="hip" /><map name="tfAbonament" id="m_34">
<area shape="rect" coords="259,545,457,582" href="#plata" alt="" />
</map></h2>
        <p class="den_articol">Why this text text?</p>
<p class="text_obisnuit">test text text</p>
        <p class="text_obisnuit">test text text</p>
  <p class="text_obisnuit2">test text text</p>
    </div>
    <p align="justify" class="text_obisnuit style3">&nbsp;</p>
   
       <!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->
```

The next step should be getting the content from file, in PowerShell this is commonly done with `Get-Content`, then just pipeline the result of the first cmdlet to the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter the results using regex match, if the statement is true the line is included else it isn't, that's how you filter results, and `where` is an alias of `where-object`.

```
get-content D:\test.html | where {$_ -match "ARTICOL|<P class=(.*)</p>"}
```

And the output:

```
  <!-- ARTICOL START -->
            <td><h1 class="den_articol" itemprop="sfe">My text here</h1></td>
        <p class="den_articol">Why this text text?</p>
<p class="text_obisnuit">test text text</p>
        <p class="text_obisnuit">test text text</p>
  <p class="text_obisnuit2">test text text</p>
       <!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->
```

I will admit it isn't exactly what you wanted but it is pretty close.

Now the same result can be achieved using a combination of for loop and if statement:

```
$html = get-content D:\test.html
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $html.count; $i++) {
    if ($html[$i] -match "ARTICOL|<P class=(.*)</p>") { $html[$i] }
}
```

The first line gets the content of the file, by default get-content gets the content line by line, so the result is an array, we save it in a variable, then loop through the array using index, in PowerShell the first element in array has the index of 0 and therefore last element is indexed the count of elements in the array minus 1, we loop through the array element by element and check whether if it matches the regex, and if it matches we print it to screen.

---

Update: To do this to a bunch of files, just use this code (you have to replace the placeholder to use the code):

```
$files = (Get-ChildItem -Path "path\to\folder" -Force -Recurse -filter *.html).FullName
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $content = Get-Content -Path $file
    $content = $content | where {$_ -match "ARTICOL|(<P class=(.*)</p>)"}
    Set-Content -Path $file -Value $content
}
```

Comment: thanks, @xeнεi-Ξэnвϵς  The output works in Powershell, but it does not modify the `test.html` So, You just need to write $output to the file. Also, I must modify several files, not just `test.html` and I must keep the original names for every modify html file in the Output folder. Can this be done?

Comment: This will also remove everything that is not inside the comments `<!-- ARTICOL START -->` and `<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->`

Comment: hello @xeнεi-Ξэnвϵς Your Poweshell code is almost good. Except, after run the code, the tags `<td>..</td>` and `<h1>..</h1>` are still there. So, must remain only the `<p class  .. </p>` tags

Answer (score 1):

Works in Powershell:

```
$sourcedir = "C:\Folder1\"
 $resultsdir = "C:\Folder2\"
 Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedir -Filter *.html | ForEach-Object{
     $output=@()
     $content = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName
     $start = $content | Where-Object {$_ -match '<!-- ARTICOL START -->'} 
     $final = $content | Where-Object {$_ -match '<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->'} 
     for($i=0;$i -lt $content.Count;$i++){
         if(($i -gt $content.IndexOf($start)) -and ($i -lt $content.IndexOf($final))){
             if($content[$i] -notmatch '<p class='){
                 continue
             }
         }
         $output += $content[$i]
     }
     $output | Out-File -FilePath $resultsdir\$($_.name)
 }
```

Thank you, **IanXue-MSFT** that help me with this answer [HERE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/393875/powershell-select-and-delete-everything-that-is-fr.html)